# Reference for linear algebra in a more generalized way

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm studying the chapter VII in the [classical Hungerford's algebra book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387905189) and he treat matrices in a very generalized way (with entries in a ring with unit) and their relationship with $R$-homomorphisms.

I'm looking for another book with the same content, but with more detailed material (maybe a little more deeper, but not necessarily) to accompany the Hungerford's book.

Answer (score 1):

I think Advanced Linear Algebra (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Vol. 135) by Steven Roman http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=advanced+linear+algebra+
is the book you are looking for.  This probably goes deeper than Hungerford, with linear algebra as a part of abstract algebra.